# Extracting data from a chart that appears on the website

Tags: excel, vba

The CNN website includes a chart for each stock with a price forecast. I was unable to scrape the forecast data with the following code.

For example: the URL about Tesla stock is:
[https://edition.cnn.com/markets/stocks/TSLA](https://stackoverflow.com)

The code is:

```
Sub CNN_Data()
Dim request As Object
Dim response As String
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim website As String
Dim price As Variant

stock = "TSLA"
website = "https://edition.cnn.com/markets/stocks/" & stock
Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
request.Open "GET", website, False
request.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
request.send
response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)
html.body.innerHTML = response

price = html.getElementByClassName("high-price").Item(0).innerText
 
End Sub
```

I get an error message when the code reaches the line:

"price = html.getElementByClassName("high-price").Item(0).innerText"

The error message is:
"Object doesn't support this property or method".

What is wrong on my code or does anyone know to suggest a helpful code?

Comment: Please show the full code you are using and inclide `Option Explicit` - this will show up where this sort of error has arisen.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I updated the question according to the comments